# What is the name for a barrier where a railway line crosses a road?

Tags: word-choice

What do you call the barrier outlined in red in the picture below?

So far, I have found names like *lifting barriers*, *boom barriers*...
[image]

Comment: And what's wrong with those words?

Comment: “What” do you call. Never “how” In English.

Comment: They're called level crossing gates/barriers when at a level crossing, but something else when at a car park entrance, security gate, or other location. Are you referring to the design of the barriers, or their location?

Comment: "*passage à niveau*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Gate arm**: movable wooden barrier of a level crossing.

[Visual Dictionary](https://infovisual.info/en/transport/level-crossing)
[image: Gate arm]

---

**gate arm** Moving barrier that blocks the road to stop vehicles from crossing the tracks.

[ikonet.com](http://www.ikonet.com/en/visualdictionary/transport-and-machinery/rail-transport/highway-crossing.php)
[image: Gate arm]

(It appears that the French *clignotant* was inadvertently left on the top illustation.)

Answer (score 4):

In the US, these are called **crossing gates**.

Here’s a definitive reference at the NJ Transit website.
https://www.njtransit.com/press-releases/nj-transit-reminds-drivers-rail-crossing-safety

NJ Transit is the largest statewide public transit operator in the United States.  Close to New York and Philadephia, most of their track is separated grade, but out in the suburbs and the exurbs (most of the state, basically), there are plenty of grade crossings with variety of crossing gates.

Comment: As every American child knows, railroad crossings are marked with the X-rated icon RAIL SING CROS ROAD, which must be recited whenever the car passes one.

Answer (score 1):

In Britain the place where a highway crosses a railway track is called a “level crossing”, and although the term [“barrier”](https://www.heathcote-electronics.co.uk/uk-barrier-crossing.html) can be used for object outlined in the picture, the word “gate” is more usual:

> [Level crossing gate](https://www.railwaysignallingconcepts.in/railway-interlocking-of-level-crossing-gate-lc-gate/)

The adjectival embellishments of “barrier” in the question would be both unnecessary and sound odd to a Briton.

I suspect US usage is different — Merriam-Webster gives “grade crossing” — although I imagine “barrier” is used rather than gate.

Comment: In the US, "grade crossing" is the road itself where the train is crossing at the same level, not the gate/barrier/mechanical arm that comes down and prevents you from crossing.

Comment: In Britain, they're also called _level crossing gates_ because the barrier usually has a [gate-like metal structure](https://cdn.prgloo.com/media/93eb14bdcec241e0ad1ef3272ec9a955.jpg?width=1135&height=960).

Comment: And also [half-barriers](https://www.networkrailmediacentre.co.uk/resources/balnacra-sco) where each barrier only extends half-way across the road.

Comment: @KillingTime — Correct. More common than "barrier". I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I grew up believing that the level crossing barriers were called "wig wags". I thought it was just a saying that my mother made up because she didn't know the true name. I was listening to the news on my local radio station the other day and they referred to them as wig wags! I was shocked! It's not listed in the dictionary as an English word. I am totally confused.

Comment: Are you sure it was describing the barrier? [Wigwags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigwag_(railroad)) are a type of pendulum that was used at railroads to warn drivers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).